# Showing progress of JSONDecoder.decode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, decodable

I've got a JSON similar to this:

```
{
    "status": "ok"
    "items": [
        {},
        {},
        ...
    ]
}
```

And I'm decoding this using CoreDataCodable via

```
struct ItemsResponse: Decodable {
    var items: ManagedObjectsUpsert<Item>

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items = "items"
    }
}
```

My question is, is there any way to get the progress of the decoder so that I can implement a progress bar?

Comment: No, there isn’t.

Comment: Did you mean progress of URLSession data task?

Comment: @Frankenstein no. I'm getting the JSON from a data task, yes, but I want to get the progress of the decoder adding the objects to the database.

Comment: You are probably better of with an [activity indicator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview)

Comment: thought of that, but I really need to show the progress as a percentage.

Comment: Hay you want to show a progress bar only for decoding time ?? right ?

Comment: Decoding is essentially a synchronous process so it doesn't really make sense to have a progress bar for it

Comment: :( What if you have 30 complex objects in that JSON though?